# error- toMatchSnapshot() must be called during the test (playwright + ts)

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs, playwright-test, snapshot-testing, playwright-typescript

In project I used playwright + typescript + cucumber.
I have problem with comparing screenshots using 'toMatchSnapshot()' method.
In definition steps file I used it like that

```
expect(await productSelectionPage.getLogoBackground()).toMatchSnapshot('e2e/stepDefinitions/graphics/picture.png');
```

When I started test I'm getting error 'Error: toMatchSnapshot() must be called during the test'.
Do you know what I have to do to fix this error? :)
Thanks for any tips :)